# always generating exception

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow

```
private void call() 
{
    intent in=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("9424863135"));
    try
    {
        startActivity(in);
    }
    catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"yourActivity is not founded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Whenever i run this code in emulator (any version) or actual device it always throws exception and displays the message.
After some research it appeared that it needs run time permission in api 23, so I ran the code in api 22 and api 15 devices still the problem continued.
Any solution?

Comment: Which exception... stack trace?

Comment: Please give a more informative title to your question. Plus posting the error log will be helpful. Also, have you added the required permission to your manifest?

Comment: @ThePerson please remove the downvote if you did, as the question has been answered

Comment: @awadheshsingh Rename your post, what use a post named "always generating exception" to anyone else trying to find out about the permissions required for calling? I won't be removing my downvote until this is actually a question and answer that is useful for other people rather than just asking others to fix your own immediate problem. A stack trace, as requested, would also be useful to others facing a similar problem.

Comment: @ThePerson suggest the edits i will merge them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in api 23 you will need to ask for runtime permission to make phone calls.
to know how to ask runtime permission check this link to [Android developer page](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

On button click for making a call write this code :

```
 if (!(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M)) {
                checkCallingPermission();
            } else {
                //call your method to make call
                call();
            }
```

Method to check permission in Android M+ :

```
private void checkCallingPermission() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)) {
            Toast.makeText(ContactUsActivity.this, "Permission is needed for proper working of this app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, REQUEST_CODE_CALL);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, REQUEST_CODE_CALL);
        }

    } else {
        call();
    }
}
```

And handle the callback results like this :

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CALL) {
        if (grantResults.length == 1
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            call();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(ContactUsActivity.this, "Permission is needed for proper working of this app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, REQUEST_CODE_CALL);
        }
    }
}
```

And this will be the method to make a call

```
private void call() {
    String url = "tel:" + "12234455";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: yes that's the answer i was looking for but i didn't understand it even after reading the link will you please fix my code and re post it

Comment: I had edited my answer, adding the code that you need. check and dont forget to mark this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to call a phone number.
If so, your intent is wrong.

The URI should be prefixed with `tel:`,

```
intent in=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:9424863135"));
```